# Error handling in SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to find a method for performing a bulk insert into an MSSQLServer table using SqlBulkCopy which will continue in the event of errors, and return a datatable of any rows which could not be inserted.

When I've attempted this with SqlBulkCopy, due to the transactional nature, the whole operation has failed and rolled back.

At the moment, I'm leaning toward using a loop to iterate the datatable's rows and perform an insert on each one, but if at all possible, I'd prefer to use the SqlBulkCopy method in keeping with the rest of the operations in the class.

Is it possible to instruct SqlBulkCopy to run in a non-transactional way, or am I better off just using a loop and individual inserts?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has been answered many times I think. Basic idea is to either only insert valid data or insert to a staging table without constraints that can fail. You can then `insert...select` the correct rows over to the real target table.

Comment: The problem with an unconstrained staging table would be, how will I know if there is a problem with the data I'm trying to insert without the constraint. I think looping and inserting each individual row is about the best option at this point. Apologies if this has been answered before, I did search but couldn't find anything solid. Thank you for your help

Comment: You can validate the data in the staging table and remove everything that is invalid. That can be done in one statement. That's vastly more efficient than RBAR processing.